# reset user password using only email

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I am using asp.net built-in login components and I have disabled the security question and answer and 
I am trying to allow the user to reset his password using only his email without the need for security question and answer.

Using asp.net 3.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ChangePassword class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.aspx) that is a ready to use form `<asp:changepassword` or you can use code to manual reset and change the password of your user.

```
        MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(UserIdToChangePass);

        if (mu != null)
        {
            string sTempPassword = mu.ResetPassword();
            mu.ChangePassword(sTempPassword, txtNewPasswordFromUser.Text);                
        }
```